# measuring the number of tuples of the int array

Tags: c, gcc

I use a macro to get the number of the elements of an integer array, and I could get the right result of the number of the integer array in the main function, but I got the wrong answer if I use a getData function and send the pointer of the integer array as a parameter. I want to know why I got this wrong answer. Thank you!

the code of my program as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTHOFINTARRAY(intArray) ((int)(sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(int)))

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[] = {5,8,9,4,11,7,15,25,1};

    int getData(int *data);
    printf("%d\n", LENGTHOFINTARRAY(a));
    getData(a);

    return 0;
}

int getData(int *data)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < LENGTHOFINTARRAY(data); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", LENGTHOFINTARRAY(data), data[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and the result of my program is:

9

1, 5

I use gcc as my compiler.

Comment: Many duplicates for this.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is in the c-faq - here you go: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `int* data` is just `int*` and not `int[9]` like in `main`. The size of `int*` is is the size of any other pointer (4 or 8 bytes usually). There is no way to get the size of an array from the pointer.
And since arrays can't be passed by value in C (unless inside a struct or something) you have to pass the length of the array.

Comment: So, if I want to get the number of the integer array in my getData fuction, I must send the sent the number of the integer array as a parameter? Could I have another way the get this?

Comment: Yes, you must send the size as a parameter and no, there is no other way.

Comment: No, there's no way to tell how big an array is if you only have a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @liuzeli You can avoid passing the array size as a separate parameter if you set the final value of the array to a sentinel value that will never otherwise appear in the array.  Other functions can then iterate through the array, stopping when they find the element with the sentinel value.

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` sees `data` as an `int*`. It does not know how long it is.

You cannot determine the size of an array that is passed as a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined

```
int a[] = {5,8,9,4,11,7,15,25,1};

    int getData(int *data);
    printf("%d\n", LENGTHOFINTARRAY(a));
    getData(a);
```

so when you call "getData(a)" then it means you are passing the address of the very first element as &a[0];

so inside you function getData() as

```
int getData(int *data)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < LENGTHOFINTARRAY(data); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", LENGTHOFINTARRAY(data), data[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

the data is just a pointer to integer & it gets the pointer or address of the a[0];
so your macro now sees data as pointer to int. which causes the result as u have gotten.